How does one add a mathematical bar over a character in Vim?
I'd like to be able to type characters "a bar," "e bar," and so on - as variable names for vectors, let's say - but I can't find them in :digraphs. I've tried searching digraphs.txt and come up empty. It's possible this isn't an option in Vim, but I thought I'd ask here before writing it off.

You will have to be more precise about what you want, because it is very easy to obtain a character with a macron:
<C-k>a-

which :digraphs definitely has:

which is also listed in :help digraphs under :help digraph-table-mbyte:

a list that is a bit redundant given this other list:
char name           char    meaning
Exclamation mark    !       Grave
Apostrophe          '       Acute accent
Greater-Than sign   >       Circumflex accent
Question mark       ?       Tilde
Hyphen-Minus        -       Macron
Left parenthesis    (       Breve
Full stop           .       Dot above
Colon               :       Diaeresis
Comma               ,       Cedilla
Underline           _       Underline
Solidus             /       Stroke
Quotation mark      "       Double acute accent
Semicolon           ;       Ogonek
Less-Than sign      <       Caron
Zero                0       Ring above
Two                 2       Hook
Nine                9       Horn

Equals              =       Cyrillic (= used as second char)
Asterisk            *       Greek
Percent sign        %       Greek/Cyrillic special
Plus                +       smalls: Arabic, capitals: Hebrew
Three               3       some Latin/Greek/Cyrillic letters
Four                4       Bopomofo
Five                5       Hiragana
Six                 6       Katakana

found under :help digraphs-default.
Note that, as mentioned in the doc, the whole thing is designed after RFC 1345, and Unicode, which don't have any other way to produce "bar over character".
Note also that:

<C-k>d- produces a ð and not really a d with a macron over it,
and some combinations don't produce anything useful, like b-, c-, etc. YMMV.

Note also that there is no "overline" styling possible in Vim so all you have, really, is digraphs using a macron, with all their limitations.

Thank you - the one I needed was "e" with a macron. I didn't know the word macron until you used it; I was used to the math term "bar," such as when denoting a vector. And I didn't find them in the digraphs table, but other than visually scanning it, I'm not sure how best to search it.

The characters you want can at least be approximated using an appropriate combining character. For example,

ā = a + U+0304 (combining macron)
a̅ = a + U+0305 (combining overline)
a͞ = a + U+035e (combining double macron)

How you enter such characters may depend on your operating system, keyboard layout, etc.
I'll note that I see differences in the combined characters both in my editing box and in how they render in my web browser in the final page, which brings me to a critical point: vim is a text editor, not a typesetter. You are limited by what Unicode defines and what fonts are available to render Unicode characters.

Thank you. My use case is for representing certain Greek letters when tracing the etymology of English words, which means I mostly need vowels, not arbitrary letters. I looked into how to use combining characters, and it looks quite complicated. For simplicity's sake, I am going to stick with digraphs.

You can define your own digraph for the combining mark, e.g., if you define CO as the digraph for the combining overline, you could type aCO to get a̅. vim.stackexchange.com would be a better place to look (and ask, if necessary) for how to define a digraph for an arbitrary Unicode character.
